# How to supply current content of framebuffer as texture to a shader?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Is it possible to write a shader that uses `gl_LastFragData` and stores that value to a supplied buffer in the fragment shader, and then that buffer can be used in another subsequent shader?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are asking for. But you can implement ping-pong rendering between 2 render targets. This way, you render first into texture A and then use `texture2D()` to access it and render into final texture B. `gl_LastFragData` is meant primarily to create custom blending modes, not for extracting data into separate buffer. And you won't have access to `gl_LastFragData` if your GL hardware doesn't support `EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch` (`NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch`, `APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch`, etc.) extension.

Comment: Why not just copy texture?

Comment: I want to create a gaussian blur shader that blurs whatever is already in the main framebuffer.  My knowledge of opengl is limited.  Perhaps there is an easier/different way of doing this, but I wondered whether and how this could be done using this strategy.  I have used gl_LastFragData already.

Comment: @keltar How can I copy content of main framebuffer into a texture to be supplied to my shader?

Comment: @andrewz you could use glCopyTexSubImage2d, but it could be slow. It would be better if you'll render scene to texture in the first place (look for framebuffer objects documentation), then use it as shader input texture and render either into different texture or directly onto screen.

Comment: You can find a description of technique here: http://androidworks-kea.blogspot.com/2013/10/developers-notes-iii-simple-dof-effect.html